# How to change the size of the legend text in grid_legend command in R?

Tags: r, fonts, size, reduce

I am using the following command to draw legend on my plot. Since I have more than 30 labels, some of my labels are outside of my plot. I need to know how to decrease the size of my plot.

```
grid_legend(0.9, 0.6, pch, col, labels, title="Bacterial Phyla")
```

I tried using `cex=1` command and `text.width=0.5` comment. But it didn't work. I get an error stating:

```
"Error in grid_legend(0.9, 0.5, pch, col, labels, text.width = 0.5, title = "Bacterial Class") : 
  unused argument (text.width = 0.5)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most reproducible example. But, try setting the cex and other parameters you want to change outside the legend function with par, for example `par(cex=2)`.